# What's the input_size for the RNN Model in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm just starting with deep learning, and I've been told that Keras would be the best library for beginners.

Before that, for the sake of learning, I built a simple feed forward network using only numpy so I could get the feel of it.

In this case, the shape of the weight matrix was `(len(X[0]), num_neurons)`. The number of features and the number of neurons. And it worked.

Now, I'm trying to build a simple RNN using Keras. My data has 7 features and the size of the layer would be 128.

But if I do something like `model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=(7, 128)))`it says it's wrong.

So I have no idea what this `input_dim` should be.

My data has 5330 data points and 7 features (shape is (5330, 7)).
Can someone tell me what the `input_dim` should be and why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input_dim` is just the shape of the **input** you pass to this layer. So:

- `input_dim = 7`

There are other options, such as:

- `input_shape=(7,)` -- This argument uses `tuples` instead of integers, good when your input has more than one dimension
- `batch_input_shape=(batch_size,7)` -- This is not usually necessary, but you use it in cases you need a fixed batch size (there are a few layer configurations that demand that)

Now, the size of the output in a Dense layer is the `units` argument. Which is 128 in your case and should be equal to `num_neurons`.

Comment: Thank you! Is this only for the Dense layer? Or every other type of layers, like LSTM, would be 7 as well?

Comment: The Syntax is the same for all layers, but recurrent and Conv1D need two dimensions per sample, and conv2D needs 3.